# integrating with a non thread safe service, while maintaining back pressure, in a concurrent environment using Futures, akka streams and akka actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am using a third party library to provide parsing services (user agent parsing in my case) which is not a thread safe library and has to operate on a single threaded basis. I would like to write a thread safe API that can be called by multiple threads to interact with it via Futures API as the library might introduce some potential blocking (IO). I would also like to provide back pressure when necessary and return a failed future when the parser doesn't catch up with the producers.

It could actually be a generic requirement/question, how to interact with any client/library which is not thread safe (user agents/geo locations parsers, db clients like redis, loggers collectors like fluentd), with back pressure in a concurrent environments.

I came up with the following formula:

1. encapsulate the parser within a dedicated Actor.
2. create an akka stream source queue that receives ParseReuqest that contains the user agent and a Promise to complete, and using the ask pattern via mapAsync to interact with the parser actor.
3. create another actor to encapsulate the source queue.

Is this the way to go? Is there any other way to achieve this, maybe simpler ? maybe using graph stage? can it be done without the ask pattern and less code involved?

the actor mentioned in number 3, is because I'm not sure if the source queue is thread safe or not ?? I wish it was simply stated in the docs, but it doesn't. there are multiple versions over the web, some stating it's not and some stating it is.

Is the source queue, once materialized, is thread safe to push elements from different threads?

(the code may not compile and is prone to potential failures, and is only intended for this question in place)

```
class UserAgentRepo(dbFilePath: String)(implicit actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory) {

import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
implicit val askTimeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

// API to parser - delegates the request to the back pressure actor
def parse(userAgent: String): Future[Option[UserAgentData]] = {
  val p = Promise[Option[UserAgentData]]
  parserBackPressureProvider ! UserAgentParseRequest(userAgent, p)
  p.future
}

// Actor to provide back pressure that delegates requests to parser actor
private class ParserBackPressureProvider extends Actor {
  private val parser = context.actorOf(Props[UserAgentParserActor])

  val queue = Source.queue[UserAgentParseRequest](100, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
    .mapAsync(1)(request => (parser ? request.userAgent).mapTo[Option[UserAgentData]].map(_ -> request.p))
    .to(Sink.foreach({
      case (result, promise) => promise.success(result)
    }))
    .run()

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case request: UserAgentParseRequest => queue.offer(request).map {
      case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued =>
      case _ => request.p.failure(new RuntimeException("parser busy"))
    }
  }
}

// Actor parser
private class UserAgentParserActor extends Actor {
  private val up = new UserAgentParser(dbFilePath, true, 50000)
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case userAgent: String =>
      sender ! Try {
      up.parseUa(userAgent)
    }.toOption.map(UserAgentData(userAgent, _))
  }
}

private case class UserAgentParseRequest(userAgent: String, p: Promise[Option[UserAgentData]])

private val parserBackPressureProvider = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props[ParserBackPressureProvider])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use actors for this?

It does not seem like you need all this complexity, scala/java hasd all the tools you need "out of the box":

```
 class ParserFacade(parser: UserAgentParser, val capacity: Int = 100) {
    private implicit val ec = ExecutionContext
      .fromExecutor(
         new ThreadPoolExecutor(
           1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue(capacity)
         )
      )

   def parse(ua: String): Future[Option[UserAgentData]] = try {
     Future(Some(UserAgentData(ua, parser.parseUa(ua)))
       .recover { _ => None }
   } catch {
     case _: RejectedExecutionException => 
       Future.failed(new RuntimeException("parser is busy"))
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dima, it does seem much more clean and easier to implement. I guess as the local parser is not thread safe, and given the executor is made out of only 1 thread, this implementation is indeed thread safe. one thing, any idea how to catch the exception to a potential rejection to the pool in case the queue is full ? Do you know if the akka stream source queue is thread safe ???

Comment: Re. catch exception: I updated the code to show that. Not sure about akka queues, would have to look at the implementation ...

Comment: Hi Dima, I think you have to add "throw _" as the discard policy, otherwise it doesn't work. furthermore, I think you also need a second executor (unbounded one) to execute the callback in case the bounded one is busy. all in all it's still less code than what i previously had in mind.

Comment: .fromExecutor(
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(
          1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue(bufferSize)
        ), throw _)